# App crashes after purchasing auto renewable purchase with trial

Tags: ios, objective-c, in-app-purchase, storekit

I have been trying to implement auto renewable subscription (ARS) with trial period. I already had an app with ARS implemented and it was working fine. 
Now I wanted to add trial period as well in these subscriptions. So for testing purpose I created two new products with trial period of 1 month set in them.

Now in sandbox environment, when I try to purchase these two new products from a sandbox Id from which I already had taken the subscription, the process goes smoothly without any issue. But when I try to purchase them with a new sandbox account, app crashes after reaching `updatedTransaction` observer method. In this method, I have received the receipt of the product purchase and the whole transaction details. But the app crashes after this. Restore purchase for the same product works fine.

Below is the crash log and snapshot:

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[__NSDictionaryM removeObjectForKey:]: key cannot be nil'
>   *** First throw call stack:
>   (0x186c081c0 0x18564055c 0x186b06534 0x100f052a4 0x19362ded8 0x1022e925c 0x1022e921c 0x1022ee284 0x186bb5f2c 0x186bb3b18 0x186ae2048 0x188565198 0x18cabc628 0x18cab7360 0x10065831c 0x185ac45b8)
>   libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException

[image: snapshot]

[image: Snapshot with line of crash selected]

Comment: Can you show the line on which it crashed? Click the `[AppStore productsRequest:]` method in the call stack on the left and edit your question with its code, stating the line where it crashed.

Comment: are you sure you have not checked any lines? because the it has terminated with a breakPoint

Comment: @pckill I have added snapshot as per your request.

Comment: @RawandAhmad It was an exception breakpoint

Comment: Do you have the code for `[ApStore productsRequest:didReceiveResponse:]`? I was under impression the debugger will show the line where it crashed in that function, but it seems like it is from some library.

Comment: That's the thing. As far as I have looked, this file is not in any of the libraries that I have incorporated in the project. And that's the reason, I have still not been able to find the root cause of it.

Though, by swizzling the removeObjectForKey method of NSMutableDictionary I am able to stop the crash. But the root cause is still out of my reach.

Comment: facing same issue. Did you get the reason for the same? and how to stop crash by swizzling.. can you help me in this?

Comment: @Tina, you have to swizzle the dictionary's "removeObjectForKey" method to some other method name and put in some safe checks in that method.  And you have to start swizzling just before the transaction starts and switch back to original methods once the transaction is complete.

Comment: @VikasDadheech I am able to fix the issue. In my case, I was facing the issue because I had forgot to enable the In-App purchase in capabilities section of my App. By enabling that, Crash was resolved on my end.

Comment: Well then, I guess, happy days are back again for you @Tina !! :)

Comment: @VikasDadheech Did you ever find a solution to this that doesn't involve swizzling? I'm getting this same exact crash with subscription products that include introductory pricing. My app doesn't crash if it's a standard subscription product.

Comment: We couldn't find any other solution except swizzling. But just to check how many times this kind of thing happened in live product purchase, we started tracking the calls to our swizzled functions. 

And to our surprise, it did not get called once in the marked build with live in-app purchases. We had a lot of people availing the trial, but not a single call went to swizzled method. 

we ended up removing the swizzling for our release builds. 

Our conclusion was that It was probably a sandbox issue only.

Answer (score 1):

This might not answer the above question directly, but it's the closest similar issue I could find to the one I was having. Hopefully this will save someone time if they're encountering this (skip to the bottom for the short answer).

I was getting the same stack trace exception, but for a slightly different reason:

> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[__NSDictionaryM
>   setObject:forKeyedSubscript:]: key cannot be nil'

Note `setObject:forKeyedSubscript:` and not `removeObjectForKey:` like in the above question. I was trying to purchase an IAP with Introductory Pricing, and even though I would successfully get the confirmed receipt from Apple, it would still crash. I was able to use the product after restarting the app.

I spent way too much time trying to find deallocated delegates, swizzling Foundation object methods and creating sandbox user after sandbox user. The problem all along was with incomplete information in iTunes Connect.

The reason for the crash was because the metadata on the product in iTunes connect was incomplete. I needed to add localization names and a note to the reviewer for the product to be "Ready for review" and not "Missing metadata".

**TL;DR** Make sure the product you are trying to purchase is labeled as "Ready for review" and not "Missing Metadata"

Comment: Our trial products had proper metadata and ready for review. But we kept getting these crashes in sandbox.